# Remove MVVMCross from UnitTest (Ressource.Attribute Error)

Tags: mvvmcross, android-resources, uninstallation

I have a Unit-Test Project where i used MVVMCross for Dependency Injection, but since i made a Implementation of the Library which i tested for UWP, i kinda wanted to use the Unit-Test for both Implementations.

For that purpose i used Compiler Switches and ended up removing MVVMCross. 
But when i uninstall it from the packages i always get **"Resource.Attribute" does not contain a definition for "MvxBind"** and some other MVVMCross attributes.

I rebuilded the project. I deleted the obj and bin folder and looked through every file in the project folder, but i cant find a thing why it keeps adding those attributes to my Ressource.Designer.cs

If i add MVVMCross back and just dont use it all, obviously it works. But i kinda want to remove it there, since it is just overkill.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking here. You want to use MvvmCross in your UnitTest, but you don't want to reference it?

Comment: I added it to my project before and now i basically just want to remove MvvmCross again. But it keeps adding the references to the Ressource.Designer.cs, while it actually shouldnt do that anymore, since i removed it from the project via nuget.

Comment: MvvmCross.Binding on Android adds those, make sure you don't reference that

Comment: There is no reference in the project anymore and it still adds those. Is it maybe cus i reference it in other projects of the solution?

Comment: Other projects, plugins, libraries that uses it, yes.